# How to pull index status through the Search Console API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-search-console

I'm using [Search Console API (Webmaster Tools API)](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/) with Google App Script.

And then I want to get [the Index status](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2642366?hl=en) to know how many contents are in the Google index.

But I could not find the suitable API... What is good solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Went over the Search Console API and found none with regard to pulling index status. Also found the same question in [this google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/webmasters/KIUsaXpquKY;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/category$3Awebmaster-tools%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) and answer also states that there's no such feature yet. Try to file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Admin).